# CultureNotFoundException .NET Core 2.1

Tags: http, web, .net-core, runtime-error

Recently I published a .NET 2.1 Core Web App to Azure with successful deployment. Upon realizing that the pictures to my site would not load, I realized I had to make changes to my code, so I did and republished successfully. This time however, I could not deploy as I got this error:

```
CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name anguageVersionAttribute is an invalid culture identifier.

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitializeFromName(string name, bool useUserOverride)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue. All I had to do was make a new publish profile for my web app and republish to Azure.